# How to use compass mixins in Yeoman?

Tags: compass-sass, yeoman

```css
&:hover {
            background-color:white;
            color:black;
            font-weight:bold;
            @include border-top-radius(3px); /* not 
        }
```

Syntax error: Undefined mixin: border-top-radius(3px)

Answer (score 1):

Add the compass import to the top of the SASS file:

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Also - for others out there - I had a similar error, but had included the import. My problem was forgetting to start the mixin line with the "@include" flag.

```
@include border-top-radius(3px);
```